# EconnRefused Heroku Trailhead Quick Start: Heroku Connect Change and Redeploy the Application

Tags: heroku, salesforce, heroku-connect

working through the salesforce trailhead on Heroku Connect.  Everything has worked up until the step Change and Redeploy the Application.  After stopping the application and modifying the server.js file, I am unable to connect/update the database records. restored the server.js file, same issue. I am on windows 7, npm --version = 4.6.1, node --version = v8.11.1, git --version = 2.14.2.windows.2.  Any idea what might be causing the following error:

```
{ 
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432 
}
```

Thanks!

Here's the commands to set/start the application:

```
SET DATABASE_URL=`heroku config:get DATABASE_URL`
SET PGSSLMODE=require
npm start
```

Here's the contents of the server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var pg = require('pg');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/update', function(req, res) {
    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function (err, conn, done) {
        // watch for any connect issues
        if (err) console.log(err);
        conn.query(
            'UPDATE salesforce.Contact SET Phone = $1, MobilePhone = $1 WHERE LOWER(FirstName) = LOWER($2) AND LOWER(LastName) = LOWER($3) AND 
LOWER(Email) = LOWER($4)',
            [req.body.phone.trim(), req.body.firstName.trim(), 
req.body.lastName.trim(), req.body.email.trim()],
            function(err, result) {
                if (err != null || result.rowCount == 0) {
                  conn.query('INSERT INTO salesforce.Contact (Phone, 
MobilePhone, FirstName, LastName, Email) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)',
                  [req.body.phone.trim(), req.body.phone.trim(), 
req.body.firstName.trim(), req.body.lastName.trim(), 
req.body.email.trim()],
                  function(err, result) {
                    done();
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(400).json({error: err.message});
                    }
                    else {
                        // this will still cause jquery to display 'Record 
updated!'
                        // eventhough it was inserted
                        res.json(result);
                    }
                  });
                }
                else {
                    done();
                    res.json(result);
                }
            }
        );
    });
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: What command are you running when you see this error? Or are you seeing it in your application logs?

Comment: @Bradley Hi, the app is serving a web page that allows the user to enter information to update a salesforce contact record.  when the user clicks submit the application attempts to connect to the Heroku Postgres database.  That's when the error is returned.

Comment: Can you add the `server.js` file to your question?

Comment: @Bradley, added the contents of server.js

Comment: Are you seeing these error in your Heroku app or locally? Wherever it is, `DATABASE_URL` is set incorrectly.

Comment: I tried changing this command from:
SET DATABASE_URL=`heroku config:get DATABASE_URL`
to:
SET DATABASE_URL=`heroku config:get [DATABASE_URL value from https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/APP_NAME/settings `

got the same error, indicating 127.0.0.1.  Do I need to set the database url somewhere else?

Comment: What do you see when you actually deploy the application?

Comment: Hi, I added a console.log to see what the value process.env.DATABASE_URL contains.  instead of the url to the database, the console.log shows  'heroku config:get DATABASE_URL'.  If I run heroku config:get DATABASE_URL from the command line, I get the url to the database.  As a test, I added a line to server.js just before the line that calls pg.connect and set the value of process.env.DATABASE_URL to the url of the database.  rna the program locally and it worked.  So it looks like the process.env.DATABASE_URL is not being set properly at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to connect to a local database (`127.0.0.1`) where you need to connect to the Heroku Postgres instance. [This is the relevant config](https://github.com/jamesward/heroku-connect-phone-change/blob/master/server.js#L13) from the application code. Make sure that server.js is connecting to `DATABASE_URL` which Heroku manages on your behalf.